# how to use console.log with nextjs?

Tags: javascript, next.js, console.log

I'm trying to show the return of an API call with `console.log`, but I don't have anything in the console (browser and visual studio code).
Only the `console.log` in the `RouteStatus` function works, but the result is undefined.

The code is as follows:

```
import RefreshButton from "./refreshButton";
import { getHealthStatus } from "@/lib/health";

export async function getStaticProps() { 
    const health = await getHealthStatus()

    console.log(health) // KO
    console.log({health}) // KO
    console.log("test"); // KO
    return {
      props: {
        health
      },
    };
  }


export default function RouteStatus({ health }) {

    console.log(health) // OK but undefined
    console.log({health}) // OK but undefined
    console.log("test"); // OK 

    return (
        <>
        </>
    )
}
```

And the getHealthStatus function :

```
export async function getHealthStatus() {
    // Fetch data from an external API endpoint
    const res = await 
    fetch('https://exemple.net:8080/healthcheck')
    if (!res.ok) throw new Error('failed to fetch data')

    console.log(res.json()) // KO

    return res.json();
  }
```

Is it possible to use it everywhere?

I'm trying to display variables in the console.
I expect the result to show in the console.

Comment: When something is running on the server, like in `getStaticProps`, it will be displayed in the console window where you ran `yarn dev`, when something runs in the browser, it will be logged to the browser console.

Comment: Hello,

As I said, I have nothing in the Chrome console, and the terminal (integrated into vsc). The output is as follows:


- ready started server on [::]:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
- event compiled client and server successfully in 160 ms (20 modules)
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 166 ms (20 modules)
- wait compiling /page (client and server)...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 1692 ms (519 modules)
- wait compiling...
- event compiled successfully in 218 ms (286 modules)

Comment: Yes you need to request the page first for the output in `getStaticProps` to be logged since in development mode, SSG and ISR behave on a per-request basis, similar to SSR.

Comment: I used the following method which worked as expected :https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

So, as for me I just had to figure out the type of component I was using the console.log in, if it's a server component, it will come in your dev console.

For Client Component in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

getStaticProps() Is a function that only runs on the server on a next js project. If you check your terminal where your app is running, you can see it there instead of the browser's console.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).